# Adding a button to woocommerce edit subscription page (admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How would I go about adding a custom button to the edit-subscription page. 
I'm not sure of the hook to add it in here.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the hook that is required to add your content here.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'after_order_details_func' );
function after_order_details_func() {
    echo '<button>Your Button</button>';
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone else browsing.